# Can Service Fabric State be replicated across Partitions and/or Clusters?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Can Service Fabric partitioning be used to actively manage the geographical location of subsets of the application state? I want to make sure a given partition is deployed within a specific region only.

Comment: Are you talking about Azure Regions? Your question is a little vague...

Comment: Well, I guess allocating Azure resources to locations in general, means configuring them for a region. But I specifically ask if a partition (also an Azure tech term) can be assigned to a region.

Comment: You have some ambiguity in your questions. region... partition... Overloaded terms in the world of Service Fabric. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an Azure based cluster, it uses Storage Accounts to store the Virtual Machines' disks, which contain the Service Fabric state.

Storage Accounts can be configured to store data redundantly in one (LRS) or two (GRS) [Azure Regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-redundancy).

You control where your Storage Accounts are created, so you decide where your data will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Service Fabric to maintain application state, then you can not duplicate that state across multiple Service Fabric Clusters. This applies to hosting multiple Azure Service Fabric Clusters both on-premises as well as in the same or multiple Azure Regions.

It is my understanding that the state within a Service Fabric Partition is not shared or sharable between multiple partitions.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning

Comment: I see, but partitioning is done within the bounds of a single cluster afaik.

Comment: @Landrew It is my understanding that the state within a Service Fabric Partition is not shared or sharable between multiple partitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Azure Service Fabric cluster that spans multiple Azure Regions (most people don't) then you can constrain or optimize the location of a particular named service instance via [placement policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-advanced-placement-rules-placement-policies).

The options are:

1. Invalid domains
2. Required domains
3. Preferred domains
4. Disallowing replica packing

Example snippet:

```
ServicePlacementInvalidDomainPolicyDescription invalidDomain = new ServicePlacementInvalidDomainPolicyDescription();
invalidDomain.DomainName = "fd:/DCEast"; //regulations prohibit this workload here
serviceDescription.PlacementPolicies.Add(invalidDomain);
```

Grab your favorite reflector and look at the things that derive from `ServicePlacementPolicyDescription`